# How can I get process Id from process name? (C#)

Tags: c#, process

How can I get process id from process name on C#?

I got processes using `Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");`

But how can I get process id from this?

Answer (score 4):

That returns an array.. because you could have 1, 4, 5 or 10 notepads open at the same time.

So, you could list them like this:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
foreach(var p in processes)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Notepad process found with ID: {p.Id}");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// To get NOTEPAD.EXE processes
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
foreach (var process in processes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("PID={0}", process.Id);
    Console.WriteLine("Process Handle={0}", process.Handle);                
}
```

Code taken from [here](http://csharp.tips/tip/article/955-how-to-get-process-handle-from-process-name-in-csharp).